# could not load controls from the android support library

Tags: android, xamarin.android, android-xml, designer, nuget-package-restore

I had installed a nugget package for showing gift image as a loading indicator and implemented in the following LoginActivity.xml

LoginActivity.xml

```
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/bglogin">
    <ImageView
        android:src="@drawable/iconwhitecomplete"
        android:layout_width="40dp"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="310dp"
        android:id="@+id/imageView1" />
    <TextView
        android:text="@string/Login"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:textSize="25dp"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:textColor="#fff"
        android:layout_marginTop="40dp"
        android:id="@+id/textView1" />
    
    
    <ImageView
        android:src="@drawable/asset2"
        android:layout_width="400dp"
        android:layout_height="352dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:layout_below="@+id/textView1"
        android:id="@+id/imageView2" />
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/textView2"
        android:text="@string/Email"
        android:textSize="18dp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:layout_marginTop="40dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="45dp"
        android:layout_below="@+id/textView1"
        android:textColor="#858585"/>

    <EditText
        android:inputType="textEmailAddress"
        android:layout_width="250dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="50dp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:textColor="#000"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginStart="160dp"
        android:layout_below="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:id="@+id/edtEmail" />


    <ImageView
        android:src="@drawable/email"
        android:layout_width="30dp"
        android:layout_height="30dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="65dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="45dp"
        android:layout_below="@+id/textView1"
        android:id="@+id/imgemail" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/textView3"
        android:text="@string/Password"
        android:textSize="18dp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:layout_marginTop="50dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="45dp"
        android:layout_below="@+id/textView2"
        android:textColor="#858585"/>
    <ImageView
        android:src="@drawable/pass"
        android:layout_width="30dp"
        android:layout_height="30dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="145dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="45dp"
        android:layout_below="@+id/textView1"
        android:id="@+id/imgpass"/>
    
   
    
    <TextView
        android:text="@string/Forgot"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:textSize="15dp"
        android:textColor="#858585"
        android:layout_below="@+id/textInputLayout1"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="170dp"
        android:id="@+id/tvForgotPass" />
    <ImageView
        android:src="@drawable/group237"
        android:layout_width="87dp"
        android:layout_height="85dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="240dp"
        android:layout_below="@+id/tvForgotPass"
        android:id="@+id/imglogin" />
     <!-- Loading Indicator for overall screen   -->
    <com.mohammedalaa.gifloading.LoadingView
        android:id="@+id/loading_view"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:visibility="gone"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        app:src="@drawable/spinnerloadfinal"/>

     <!-- Loading Indicator for login click button    -->
    <com.mohammedalaa.gifloading.LoadingView
        android:id="@+id/loading_view_button"
        android:layout_width="87dp"
        android:layout_height="85dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="240dp"
        android:layout_below="@+id/tvForgotPass"
        android:visibility="gone"
        app:src="@drawable/spinnerbutfinal"/>

   
    <ImageView
        android:src="@drawable/asset1"
        android:layout_width="360dp"
        android:layout_height="237dp"
        android:paddingBottom="40dp"
        android:layout_below="@+id/imglogin"
        android:id="@+id/imageViewdown" />
    <ImageView
        android:src="@drawable/group251"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="195dp"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_below="@+id/tvForgotPass"
        android:id="@+id/imageView9" />
   
    


     <android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
        app:passwordToggleEnabled="true"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="200dp"
        android:id="@+id/textInputLayout1" >
         

     <android.support.design.widget.TextInputEditText
        android:layout_width="220dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:id="@+id/editpass"    
        android:inputType="textPassword"
        android:layout_marginTop="155dp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:textColor="#000"
        android:layout_marginStart="70dp"
        android:layout_below="@+id/textView1"
         />

        
     </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

But it is showing little error sign on the corner of the designer view and it is written that:

```
could not load controls from the android support library, performing a Nuget package restore may fix 
this.
```

and is showing different misaligned view on emulator other than designer view.

I have tried deleting the Bin and Obj and building the solution again and performing the nugget package restore which is done successfully.

How can I fix this.

Here are the images of designer view and Emulator for better review of problem.
[image: Designer and Emulator view]

Comment: Hi, you could have a try with ***close VS and start again > Clean Solution > Rebuild Solution & run***.

Answer (score 2):

Usually third-party libraries are not supported by Visual Studio Android Designer, so I don't think you can view your com.mohammedalaa.gifloading.LoadingView control in the designer.

Also some namespaces of native controls has changed in lastest versions of Xamarin.Android, that's why the android.support.design.widget.TextInputEditText control isn't rendering inside the designer. I was facing the same problem with TextInputEditText so I changed it to com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputEditText and the designer worked again.

Comment: Thanks!! This wonderful answer that worked for me and saved me hours. We need more comments like this. The Xamarin VS IDE is too buggy. If it's not your code, it's the Nuget packages. If it's not Nuget, it's the VS upgrades. It's the VS Xamarin Re-bugger!

Answer (score 0):

Hi i have the sample problem before, i just clean the solution and rebuild it. Sometimes Xamarin has some issues loading all the design on previewer.

Also before doing that please check if these options; tools > option > nuget package manager the package restore allowed nuget to download missing packages and an auto check for missing packages during build in visual studio.